# iPhone ABPeoplePickerNavigationController Memory Leaks

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, abpeoplepickerview

I am going through my application killing off all the memory leaks and the analyze tool comes up with a leak using the abpeoplepickernavigationcontroller.

I understand it is something to do with a copy method? but don't know how to go about releasing it where and at the write time.

I basically need to present the modal view, select the phonenumber then drag it back into the textfield. heres my code

```
-(IBAction)openAddressBook{

    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *peoplepicker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];

    peoplepicker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:peoplepicker animated:YES];
    [peoplepicker release];

}

- (void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:

(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker {

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}

- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker 
      shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
      shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person 
                                property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier
{


    //Retrieving the phone number property of ABRecordRef

    ABMultiValueRef phoneProperty = ABRecordCopyValue(person, property);
    NSString *phone = (NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneProperty, identifier);
    phone = [phone stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    NSArray *brokenNumber = [phone componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    phone = [brokenNumber componentsJoinedByString:@""];

    if(![phonenumber.text isEqualToString:@""])
        phonenumber.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", phonenumber.text, @";"];
    phonenumber.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", phonenumber.text, phone];

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    return NO;

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is likely to be here:

```
ABMultiValueRef phoneProperty = ABRecordCopyValue(person, property);
NSString *phone = (NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneProperty, identifier);
phone = [phone stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

You get objects **copies** with `ABRecordCopyValue` and  `ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex` and they aren't released.

```
ABMultiValueRef phoneProperty = ABRecordCopyValue(person, property);
NSString *phone = (NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneProperty, identifier);
if (phoneProperty) {
    CFRelease(phoneProperty);
}

NSString *trimmedPhone = [phone stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
if (phone) {
    CFRelease(phone);
}
```

Comment: Absolutely right, CFRelease is needed. Annoyingly, it looks like ABPeoplePickerNavigationController, itself, leaks.